# If a stick of ram dies in a 4 piece kit, do I have to replace the whole kit?

Tags: memory, motherboard, desktop-computer, computer-building

The Ram kit that I have is:

CORSAIR Dominator Platinum 32GB (4 x 8GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1866 (PC3 14900) Desktop Memory Model CMD32GX3M4A1866C9

And one of the sticks died. Is is possible for me to just replace the one stick? Where can I find something like that? (I don't see it on newegg/amazon).

Also, I think that the sticks work in pairs and I'm not sure some random stick will be a exact one I need of the right pair. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to only replace the broken stick with one having the same characteristics. It does not need to be exactly the same, and can be from another manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another stick with the same specification from another vendor, It's not imperative to have your computer working. Nevertheless this setup can't guarantee full compatibility and your PC can experience small performance issues.

I recommend you to get a CMD16GX3M2A1866C9 to replace your dead stick.

Comment: Your answer works as comment

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to replace the RAM with another stick of the same model, but you do **need** to get memory with (roughly) the same specifications; speed, voltage, type.

That being said, replacing it with another of the same model will reduce potential errors or lesser performance.  For example, if one of the sticks is rated at a lesser speed, then all sticks will run at that lower speed.

If you're just asking how/where to get a single stick of that model of RAM, that would be out of the scope of SuperUser.  Any of the usual places one would buy RAM should have it available.  You could also just buy another kit; a bit over kill, but should another stick fail, you have a replacement right away.